# "Ни к чему́" и "не́ к чему" — разница

Tags: частица-не, смысл, не-или-ни

Только что, отвечая, процитировал с сайта Бунина:

> *Да, да, не к чему, прикажи подавать лошадей.*

И задумался, почему тут не *"ни к чемУ",* а *"нЕ к чему",* и в чём разница.

Нашёл [эту страничку](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/ne-k-chemu-ili-ni-k-chemu-kak-pravilno.html) в Интернете со следующими примерами:

> - спорить **не** к чему — спорить не из-за чего;
> - помогать мне **не** к чему — помогать не из-за чего.

И вот не могу я понять, что изменится, если ***не*** в этих примерах заменить на ***ни***.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, за интересный вопрос. Мне кажется, что разница между этими выражениями  не всеми понимается, в том числе это касается той  информации, которую в своих правилах отметил Розенталь.

Comment: Рад, что Вам вопрос понравился! Приступаю к чтению Ваших ответов. :)

Comment: Артем, начинайте с короткого  ответа.

Comment: Я уже так и сделал. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Подробный ответ с объяснениями (можно почитать при желании)**

Существуют две предложные формы: ***не к чему*** и ***ни к чему.***

И вот чем они интересны.

**1) Не к чему**

Падежная форма может быть местоимением при наличии глагольного управления: *К чему тут придерешься? Придраться **не к чему**.*

Падежная форма может быть наречием при отсутствии  глагольного управления: *Он ведь не лгал, ему **не к чему*** (= незачем) *было лгать.*

Старину, конечно, зря ворошить **не к чему**, а бывает, что она вроде и понадобится. [П. П. Бажов. Шелковая горка (1947)]

Но наречие ***не к чему*** с раздельным написанием предлога следует отнести **к исключениям.** В современном языке оно чаще заменяется наречием ***незачем***, которое **яснее отражает отсутствие цели.**

**2) Ни к чему**

Падежная форма может быть дополнением при наличии глагольного управления: *И **ни к чему** там не прикасайся, слышишь?* [Татьяна Толстая. Ночь (1983)]

Но падежная форма может стать самостоятельным выражением со значением "не нужно, бессмысленно".

*А главное ― **ни к чему всё это!** Более того, мне вообще наплевать на деньги, **они мне просто ни к чему**. Однако эти мысли были сейчас **ни к чему**.*

Иногда (**но реже**) в таком предложении встречается **инфинитив:** *Но доказывать или говорить что-нибудь, конечно, уже было ни к чему (=бессмысленно).* [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 1 (1964)]

**3) Ответ на вопрос**

*Ну да что вспоминать, мертвых с погоста не носят. — Да, да, **(вспоминать) не к чему,** прикажи подавать лошадей, — ответил он, отходя от окна уже со строгим лицом.*

Здесь наречная форма ***нЕ к чему*** имеет значение "нЕзачем".

Спорить ***не к чему***, помогать мне ***не к чему*** —  также  значение "незачем".

**Можно ли заменить НЕ на НИ?**

***Вспоминать ни к чему.*** Формально замена возможна: вспоминать не нужно. Но здесь может быть конкуренция со стороны местоимения: вспомнить к чему-либо. Поэтому лучше сказать: вспоминать **незачем** (не к чему).

*Спорить ни к чему, помогать мне ни к чему.*

В такой форме замена кажется неудачной, для ясности  нужно хотя бы **разделить** глагол и местоимение: спорить **было** ни к чему, спорить **здесь** ни к чему.

Хотя такой  вариант (сочетание формы ***ни к чему*** с инфинитивом) иногда встречается, но всё-таки не так часто, как именные варианты вида ***это мне ни к чему***.

**4) А что по этой теме пишет Розенталь**

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82#pp82

1. Частица ни (всегда безударная) входит в состав отрицательных местоимений никто́, ничто́, никако́й и др. и местоименных наречий нигде́, никуда́, никогда́ и др.

Запомните: местоимения и наречия с частицей-приставкой *ни* употребляются в предложениях, **ГДЕ ПРИ СКАЗУЕМОМ ИМЕЕТСЯ ОТРИЦАНИЕ НЕ** *ни к кому не обращался; ни за чем туда не ходил; нигде не гулял* (ср.: не к кому обратиться; незачем туда ходить; негде погулять).

**ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ:** ***остаться ни с чем, оказаться ни при чём, считать ни за что*** и др. Ср. также: **спорить не к чему** (‘не для чего, **незачем**’) — лекарство уже **ни к чему** (‘не нужно’ — в роли сказуемого).

Comment: Дочитываю, пока вопрос: можно Ваше "встречается редко" заменить на "встречается иногда"? Чтобы выделить не редкость, а, наоборот, поощрить факт встречаемости, ведь противопоставление "всё-таки" для этого и есть (аналогично английскому ‘happens sometimes’ instead of ‘happens rarely’).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Да, такие примеры, как *придраться не к чему,* вполне понятны, и, конечно же, они не сливаются у меня со случаями "ни к чему" в значении "не нужно, бессмысленно". Не всегда получалось разграничить как раз это "не нужно, бессмысленно" (НИ) и "незачем" (НЕ), и часто мне кажется, что и для НИ в этом значении подходит также и смысл "незачем". Но Вы действительно верно подметили, что в последних моих примерах не хватает "было" с НИ!

Comment: Я выделила текст Розенталя "аршинными буквами", где говорится, что частица НИ обычно используется в предложениях с имеющимся отрицанием в виде частицы НЕ. Но  он же подчеркивает, что этот вариант относится к исключениям. И вообще,  частица НИ   не так уж редко используется без отрицания, например: здесь ни проехать, ни пройти. Объяснить это можно так: НИ совмещает функцию отрицания и усиления.

Answer (score 2):

> И вот не могу я понять, что изменится, если не в этих примерах заменить на ни.

Не получится здесь вот так просто взять и заменить. Частица НИ крайне редко употребляется без отрицания, явного или подразумеваемого. И никогда с глаголами без отрицания.

Все примеры - и в справочниках-пособиях-учебниках, и у Sharon - суть перепевы этого простого правила.

Маленькое замечание. И Бунин, и тем более неавторитетный сайт - не лучшие источники для понимания орфографических норм. Бунин пользовался старой орфографией, а там были тонкости, непривычные современному читателю. Поэтому при переводе его на новую орфографию всегда надо быть начеку. Ну а что до сайтов... Даже если там нет явных ошибок, то методическая сторона дела обычно страдает. Вот вы пропустили ключевое упоминание использования НИ только при НЕ. А его надо аршинными буквами написать в самом видном месте...

Но это замечания общего плана, в данном случае и у Бунина, и на сайте все правильно - и более или менее понимаемо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! *Вот вы пропустили ключевое упоминание использования НИ только при НЕ.* Да в том то и дело, что я не читал от и до, а нашёл только то, что мне было интересно. На авторитетном, очень качественном сайте наверняка бы почитал внимательно при возможности, если б чувствовал, что того стоит. *И никогда с глаголами без отрицания.* Это, видимо, ключевой момент, которого я сам не сумел почувствовать. Спасибо, что указали мне на него!

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не изменится. Просто здесь "ни к чему" говорят значительно чаще. А "не к чему" – это для фраз типа "не к чему прицепиться".

Comment: Здесь это где? *А "не к чему" – это для фраз типа "не к чему прицепиться".* Я тоже думал, что только для таких, но из последних моих примеров видно, что не только.

Comment: "Здесь" - это в подобных фразах.

Answer (score 0):

**Короткий ответ:  какие фразы можно использовать в речи**

***1) Не к чему и незачем*** (ударная частица НЕ)

Карточку **не к чему** приколоть. **Не к чему** придраться.

**Незачем (не к чему)** себя обманывать.

**2) Ни к чему** (безударная частица НИ)

**Ни к чему** не придерешься.

Лишние комплексы мне **ни к чему** (не нужны).

Объяснять мне всё это **незачем (не к чему)**. Объяснять мне всё это **ни к чему** (бессмысленно, не надо).